# My database's table cleaning itself (SQL Server 2008 Express)

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I got an epic problem about my datas that in my tables. I insert some data into a table and I wait 5 or 10 mins and table clears itself. I don't know why. My application doesn't have a code bug, but I think SQL Server has a bug. PLease help...

Comment: I think if SQL server would have a bug that would clear tables without any visible reason it would have made news already...

Comment: [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: It is more likely that _your application_ has a bug. Did you close connection after inserts?

Comment: Use SQL Server profiler and record what is happening with your database right after you have added your rows.

Comment: i dont insert datas on my application, im inserting as manually.

Comment: Can you explain to us what you're doing exactly? Eg. are you inserting, then checking by a SELECT if the insert was succesful, then waiting for 5 minutes (doing absolutely nothing else in your DB) and then checking again by running a SELECT? Tell us more :-)

Comment: table clean itself while my application is not working, and if its a code bug, i would see that bug before because i use same method and same codes everytime, but i have never seen a bug like this.

Comment: Im just inserting datas manually, i select them with my application and i close application. Then i wait 5 or 10 mins and table clean itself

Comment: Could it be that you're accidentally creating tables in several spots (master / YourDB) and then querying the wrong one?

Comment: i use my application for weeks but i have never seen a bug like this. I mean, this cannot be a code bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that your code creates the database or the table each time it runs, thus seemingly deleting the data inserted.

Comment: If this is not the case you need to give some code that interacts with the database.

Comment: definitely more likely than a bug in SQL Server ..... :-))

Comment: @marc_s apparently this was the case. I did some thing like this once.  I scratched my head for about 15 minutes before looking at the query. 
no SQL bug that's for sure : )

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you commit your changes. It is my guess that the tool you are using is not committing your changes automatically because of its settings.